# how does bitmoji detect whatsapp activation on android

Tags: android, battery, activity-manager

i read that there are basiclly 2 ways to detect application launches in android:

1)poll activity manager for the foreground activity (top of the stack)

2)poll the log - although i read that you can no longer do that in newer android versions because the READ_LOG permission has been moved to higher level duo to security issues

now both methods revolve around polling every few millyseconds, this seems to me to be a huge drain on battery life.

even so i seen more than a few apps that display such an ability,
one example is bitmoji - which detects whatsapp viber etc.

what i want to know is:

how it does it, is it using the above methods?

am i wrong to assume that this will drain the battery or is it not as big dill as i seem to think?